# Read only last message from Kafka topic

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, video-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to send a video stream through a Kafka topic and doing some processing between each messages consumption. This processing takes approximately 20 milliseconds, so after 100 frames, I have a consequent latency. I can detect this latency, however, I need to be able to force my consumer to read from the latest sent frame from the moment the latency is detected. I am aware that this would lead to many frames skipped.

I am using cppkafka which is based on librdkafka.

I can't find a lead that will put me in the right path since most of the answers are either different from my problem or use concepts existing only in other languages APIs.

Any thought on the matter ?

Comment: I assume you have some sort of queue that you put the processed frames in, and the consumers gets its frames from? Then if you detect that the there's to many frames in this queue you just remove all but the last frame put into the queue?

Comment: This is the idea I have in mind but after reading the cppkafka documentation, I could not find any method that would allow to clean the queue. I believe kafka doesn't authorize consumers to clean a topic, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Then perhaps have the consumer make a tight loop where it "consumes" and *discards* (doesn't process in any way) frames until the size of the queue is equal to one, when it continues with the normal processing.

Comment: Just did this and it is working. Not the way I was thinking about but it works ! Thank you! You can put it as an answer, I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple, if kind of brute, way to do it is to check the number of frames in the queue you have. If above a certain upper threshold then do a tight loop where you "consume" and *discard* (i.e. does no processing at all) of the frames until you reach your lower threshold (in your case one).

Once that tight loop is done you resume normal processing of the queue.

Comment: This is a good solution. The alternative is to seek() to OFFSET_END, but that involves an extra broker lookup so it will add latency itself.